# Using find_first_of with a string instead of a set of predefined characters in c++

Tags: c++, string

I want to take in a code, for example ABC and check whether the characters in the code appear in that exact order in a string, for example with the code ABC, and the string HAPPYBIRTHDAYCACEY, which meets the criteria. The string TRAGICBIRTHDAYCACEY with the code ABC however does not pass, because there's a "c" before the "b" after the "a". I want to use the find_first_of function to search through my string, but i want to check for any of the characters in "code", without knowing what characters are in "code" beforehand. Here is my program so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

 int main() {

string code, str, temp;
int k = 0;
int pos = 0;

cin >> code >> str;

while (k < code.size()) {
    pos = str.find_first_of(code,pos);
    temp[k] = str[pos];
    ++k;
    ++pos;
}
cout << temp << endl; // debug. This is just outputs a newline when i 
 //run the program
if (temp == code) {
    cout << "PASS" << endl;
}
else {
        cout << "FAIL" << endl;
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: `temp[k]` is out of bound.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: So your program will result in undefined behavior. You should use `temp.push_back(...)` (though it is still incorrect because of wrong algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to find just the first character, once found, find the next in the remainder of the string, repeat until end of string or all characters found (and return false or true, respectively).

I don't think there's anything builtin for this. If the characters would need to appear directly after each other, you could use `std::string::find()` which searches for a substring, but that is not what you want.

Comment: Its not enough to check if the string contains all the right characters, they need to appear in the right order. For instance with the code ABC and string HAPPYBIRTHDAYCACEY. After i first find the A, i need to check that no more A's or C's appear before the B appears.